# error while trying to redirect from google

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a iframe in a simple html form.
the url of the iframe is changed by a simple jquery from an array of urls.

For some personal reason i have decided to use the following link to anonymize the referee and set it to google

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjRlsetwbnLAhUICY4KHez8D8cQFggcMAA&url=http%3A//xxx.net/&usg=AFQjCNHvUSBI4DhNOB-eQxcwR0SbKy0OmA&sig2=O4oc_vROP77kX1X8HJSaFA&cad=rja

Once i get to this link i the page turn white and i get this error:

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "xxx.xx". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: @Quentin Could you please tell me what are you doing that this isn't happening to you?

Comment: Creating an iframe with that URL as the src.